# Invoking method of internal API

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Using following method gives me a list of methods in internal telephony API.

```
try {
    //com.android.internal.telephony is a package in my project and
    // in  that I have an abstract Class named as Call
    c = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.Call");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Method[] aClassMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method m2 : aClassMethods) {
    Log.e("Methods",m2.getName());
}
```

I want to know how to invoke one of those method?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't give the option to the user to dial it or call it through the intent? why are you using a hidden API?

Comment: Yes Because I want to know Hen the other party answered the call or when there phone started ringing